# How do I use the principle of mathematical induction to prove whether or not $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k = \frac{(-1)^n-1}2$ is a true statement?

Tags: summation, induction

For all n elements of Natural Numbers,$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k= \frac{(-1)^n-1}2$.

I proved p(1) to be true :

$\sum_{k=1}^1 (-1)^k = (-1)^1 =-1$.

And  $\frac{(-1)^1-1}2 = \frac{(-2)}2 = -1$

So P(1) is true.

Where I'm stuck is proving whether or not P(n+1) is also true.

Then it becomes $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}-1}2$.

How do I use Induction to prove its also true?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: For example, you can write $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^n-1}2$ like this `$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^n-1}2$`.

Comment: Thank you I'll edit it. To make it clearer.

Comment: Easiest way is to do separate,  but trivial, induction proofs for even and odd n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your notation, let $P(n)$ denote the proposition 
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^k =\frac{(-1)^n-1}{2}$.

If we want to use induction to prove that $P(n)$ holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we first show $P(1)$ is true (which you've done):
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{1} (-1)^k =-1=\frac{(-1)^1-1}{2}
\end{align}

Next we must verify that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$. Indeed, if we assume that $P(n)$ holds, then 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^k &=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k + (-1)^{n+1} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^n-1}{2} + (-1)^{n+1} \\
&= \frac{-(-1)^{n+1}-1}{2} + (-1)^{n+1} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}-1}{2} 
\end{align*}

and thus $P(n+1)$ holds.

Comment: Good point. Will edit accordingly.